# Split the data in multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

```
    State      City
    DL,UP      DELHI: Karol Bag,Ashok Nagr UttarPradesh: Noida,Lucknow
```

OutPut

```
    State      City
    DL         KarolBag
    DL         Ashok Nagr
    UP         Noida
    UP         Lucknow
```

i have created a function to split the value, but while cross applying this, it is giving umnappropriate result, Like DL-Lucknow. I want the exact result.

Comment: which db you are really using????

Comment: @scaisEdge I'm assuming sql server, as it appears stack overflow recommends the MySQL tag causing new users to just click it, then they add the other DBMS tags afer

Comment: It is, MS-SQL -2012, Yup, remove the mysql tag

Comment: What is the logic to decide what DL and UP should be matched to? Based on your output it seems strange..

Comment: i have a table in which i have the full name of state-codes.

Comment: @Tjekkles DL for Delhi, UP for UttarPradesh it seems

Comment: Yes, It is a full name of codes, for that i am reffering another table.

Comment: @Ashu *don't* store data like this. Create a table where each row has one state, one city. Clean-split the data in the ETL job that loads the data. Use lookup tables to match acronyms and states. It's a lot easier to clean up dirty data *before* you load it into a database

Comment: @Ashu it's impossible from the data you posted here to guess which city entry should be matched to each state acronym. If humans can't do that, a SQL query can't do it either

Comment: Data is getting stored in sql DB from json, can't able to change.

Comment: Can you show the code for the function you created?

Comment: i would refer another table to match the data, just want a logic to split it. Suppose the given string is 'DELHI: Karol Bag,Ashok Nagr UttarPradesh: Noida,Lucknow'. then  how i can i split it.

Comment: @honeyBadger it has a table valued function, which return table, It just split the delimiter seperated value and return a table.

Comment: Need specific splitter between data that separates data for different states. With space as spliiter it will mess up. When another state with city start there is no splitter exists that is issue without which answer is not possible

Comment: Yes Pranav, was thinking the same, will have to check. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

I don't think it's an efficient way. But it gives solution if your data stored in  the same pattern.

```
DECLARE @City VARCHAR(50) = 'DL,UP', @Str VARCHAR(150)='DELHI: Karol Bag,Ashok Nagr UttarPradesh: Noida,Lucknow'

DECLARE @STr1 VARCHAR(150),@STr2 VARCHAR(150)

SELECT @Str1=REVERSE(RIGHT(REVERSE(LEFT(@Str,LEN(@Str)-CHARINDEX(':',REVERSE(@Str)))),LEN(REVERSE(LEFT(@Str,LEN(@Str)-CHARINDEX(':',REVERSE(@Str)))))-CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(LEFT(@Str,LEN(@Str)-CHARINDEX(':',REVERSE(@Str)))))))
    ,@STr2=RIGHT(@Str,LEN((RIGHT(REVERSE(LEFT(@Str,LEN(@Str)-CHARINDEX(':',REVERSE(@Str)))),LEN(REVERSE(LEFT(@Str,LEN(@Str)-CHARINDEX(':',REVERSE(@Str)))))-CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(LEFT(@Str,LEN(@Str)-CHARINDEX(':',REVERSE(@Str)))))))))

SELECT @STr1=RIGHT(@STr1,LEN(@STr1)-(CHARINDEX(':', @STr1)+1)),@STr2=RIGHT(@STr2,LEN(@STr2)-(CHARINDEX(':', @STr2)+1))

SELECT A.value [State],D.value City
FROM dbo.fn_Split(@City,',') A
INNER JOIN(
            SELECT 0 ID,* FROM dbo.fn_Split(@STr1,',')
            UNION
            SELECT 1,* FROM dbo.fn_Split(@STr2,',')
          )D ON D.ID=A.idx
```

**OutPut:**

```
State   City
DL      Karol Bag
DL      Ashok Nagr
UP      Noida
UP      Lucknow
```

Answer (score 0):

I will not say that is a good idea to store data in that way, but if so, you can try this solution (based on your example)

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--create sample data set
DECLARE @tbl AS TABLE([State] VARCHAR(100), City VARCHAR(1000));
INSERT INTO @tbl(State, City)
VALUES('DL,UP,Some', 'DELHI: Karol Bag,Ashok Nagr UttarPradesh: Noida,Lucknow SomeState: Same City1, Some City2');
----------------------------------------------------------
--Create sequence (can be replaced by recursive cte)
DECLARE @Tally TABLE(N INT);
DECLARE @i AS INT=1;
WHILE @i !=1000 BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Tally(N)VALUES(@i);
    SET @i+=1;
END;
----------------------------------------------------------
--Query (2 cte to split each fied and assign ID)
;WITH StatesSplit AS 
    (SELECT StateID=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY N), 
            StateShort=REPLACE(REPLACE(P1, LEAD(P1, 1, '') OVER (ORDER BY N), ''), ',', '')
     FROM @tbl AS E
        INNER JOIN @Tally AS T ON SUBSTRING(','+E.State, T.N, 1)=','
        CROSS APPLY(SELECT STUFF(','+E.State, 1, n, '') AS P1) AS Stage1 
     ), 
CitiesSplit AS 
    (SELECT StateLong = REPLACE(States, ':', ''), 
            ComboCities = REPLACE(REPLACE(P2, LEAD(P2, 1, '') OVER (ORDER BY N), ''), States, ''), 
            StateID=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY N)
    FROM @tbl AS E
        INNER JOIN @Tally AS T ON SUBSTRING(E.City, T.N, 1)=':'
        CROSS APPLY(SELECT REVERSE(STUFF(E.City, n+1, 999, '')) AS P1) AS Stage1
        CROSS APPLY(SELECT REVERSE(STUFF(P1+' ', CHARINDEX(' ', P1+' '), 999, '')) AS States) AS Stage2
        CROSS APPLY(SELECT STUFF(' '+City, 1, PATINDEX('%'+States+'%', City), '') AS P2) AS Stage3 
    )
--Final Output
SELECT S.StateShort, 
       C.StateLong, 
       Cities=LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(P1, LEAD(P1, 1, '') OVER (PARTITION BY S.StateShort ORDER BY N), ''), ',', ''))
FROM StatesSplit AS S
     JOIN CitiesSplit AS C ON S.StateID=C.StateID
     INNER JOIN @Tally AS T ON SUBSTRING(','+C.ComboCities, T.N, 1)=','
     CROSS APPLY(SELECT STUFF(','+C.ComboCities, 1, n, '') AS P1) AS Stage1
ORDER BY 1
```

Test below:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/822004/ccccombo

[image]